How to uninstall a driver from Device Manager using an object like winmgmts?
Both Win32_PnPEntity and Win32_PnPSignedDriver don't have methods to uninstall/remove/delete a driver.
Is there a way to do it anyway? Maybe using another class? Or maybe a different object than winmgmts?
Examples of how to find a certain driver (before uninstalling it):
In VBScript:
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Name = '" & deviceName & "'")
For Each objItem In colItems
     Exit For
Next
colItems = objItem

In AutoIt:
Local $deviceName = "..."
Local $objWMIService = ObjGet("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Local $colItems = $objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Name = '" & $deviceName & "'").itemIndex(0)

Note in Win32_PnPSignedDriver it would be FriendlyName instead of Name.


If you want to uninstall a driver, I suggest you could refer to the Doc: Using SetupAPI to Uninstall Devices and Driver Packages.

Can you show how to use it in the question's examples?
